# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis i cant find the mistake

Tags: oracle, key, primary-key

```
create table book_copies(
        book_id integer references book(book_id) on delete cascade, 
        programme_id varchar2(20) references library programme(programme_id) on delete cascade,
        nof_copies integer, 
        primary key(book_id,programme_id)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing an underscore in the table name `library_programme`.

```sql
create table book_copies(
  book_id integer references book(book_id) on delete cascade, 
  programme_id varchar2(20) references library_programme(programme_id) on delete cascade,
  nof_copies integer, 
  primary key(book_id,programme_id)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90eff9323d6115f9c99aab2b38e8d3c7)*